# In Python, how can I refer to a return-value from a function called within a generator expression?

Tags: python, syntax, generator-expression

Simplified, I want to do something like this:

```
({'publication': obj.pub_name, 'views': obj.views, } for obj = analyze_publication(p) for p in Publication.objects.all())
```

Of course, that doesn't work.

Right now, I'm using:

```
({'publication': obj.pub_name, 'views': obj.views, } for obj in (analyze_publication(p) for p in Publication.objects.all()))
```

I have no idea if the second code piece is how it's done or there's another syntax, or it's not efficient etc. I'm only 2 weeks into Python.

Comment: What's your problem with your second sample please? It is correct in Python and produces the result you want?!

Comment: @gecco: No problems x__x, just complete inexperience. The second one looks like loop inside loop to my untrained eyes... if those are even loops. I was just wondering whether that's an obviously inefficient way to go etc.

Comment: I see... in fact interesting challenge. I don't see a solution other than having a separate function construction the dict in your loop: `(toDict(analyze_publication(p)) for p in Publication.objects.all())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You <strike>have unbalanced parens</strike>, but other than that, you should have no (functional) problem nesting generator expressions.  As with list comprehensions, they quickly become unwieldy when nested.  I'd recommend moving it out to a named generator, for readability's sake.

If you are curious about performance, compare different approaches using the [disassembler](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html) or [profilers](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html).

Answer (score 2):

Just another version:

```
( dict(publication= obj.pub_name, views= obj.views) 
    for obj in map(analyze_publication, Publication.objects.all()) )
```

Comment: Looks sleek! Does it perform the same? (Sorry, my mind hasn't adjusted properly yet to Python syntax)

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map says that map returns a list (in Python3 it's a `map` object - also kind of generator), while `for obj in (...)` returns a generator. So i think `map` might perform worse. But i think it will do only with really big lists. Anyway before making any optimization - 1. be sure it's working 2. Make some profiling to be sure that this is the bottleneck.

Comment: Replace `map` by `itertools.imap` to get an iterator instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to contort the generator expression syntax to allow a name binding, I'd just use a function to produce the binding. Then it is simple:

```
def pubdict(pub):
    obj = analyze_publication(pub)
    return {"publication": obj.pub_name, "views": obj.views}

itertools.imap(pubdict, Publication.objects.all()
```